# How to configure cassandra and Mysql to spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring, cassandra

I am trying to do a small REST api in spring boot. Where the request parameter is **type**. If I provide type=Cassandra, it should fetch from my cassandra DB. Else if type=MySQL, it should fetch from mySQL DB. I don't know how to configure my application for both types of databases. I am really stuck here. Any help or any documentation is really appreciate.

My REST Api is something like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/data")
  public void getDataByDB(@PathVariable("type") String type) {
    int id = "123"
    if(type == "Cassandra") {
       // need to fetch from cassandra
       cassandraRepository.getById(id);
    } else if(type == "MySQL") {
       // need to fetch from MySQL
       sqlRepository.getById(id);
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to be corrected but I don't think it's possible to setup connections to multiple databases from one application instance so I'll leave that to Spring Boot experts to answer.

Since you mentioned that you're building an API that connects to Cassandra, I wanted to let you know that Stargate.io allows you to connect to a Cassandra cluster using RESTful, GraphQL + JSON/Document APIs. For example, adding a new record is as easy as sending a `POST` request to `/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/keyspace_name/table_name/`.

If you wanted to try it out, we've got free interactive tutorials on [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) like the [Stargate REST API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/rest). You can quickly build a proof-of-concept on [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) using the free tier (no credit card required) since Astra comes with Stargate bundled in so it's pre-configured and ready to use as soon as your database is ready. Cheers!